# How to overwrite price

Tags: expresso-store

is there a way to force or overwrite the price of an item?

I tried this: `<input type="hidden" name="items[playa{count}][price]" value="0" />`

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the Store Product Detail field for your channel has "allow user price" enabled in its settings, then you simply need to pass a field named `price` in your `store:product` form.

```
<input type="hidden" name="price" value="XX" />
```